# jQuery autocomplete disables up/down arrows in a textarea. Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a jQuery textarea with the jQuery ui autocomplete plugin applied. I'm noticing that even when the autocomplete suggestions aren't displayed, moving up and down with arrows doesn't work. Only right and left.

Any ideas why and how to resolve? Is this an option? I understand up and down being disabled when the autocomplete options are open, but if they are not open why disable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Autocomplete implementation **binds the 'keydown' event on the element itself** the plugin is applied to, and it prevents default behavior.
I guess the plugin was intended to be used on text fields and not textarea in the first place.

```
this.element
    ...
    .bind( "keydown.autocomplete", function( event ) {
        if ( self.options.disabled || self.element.propAttr( "readOnly" ) ) {
            return;
        }

        suppressKeyPress = false;
        var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
        switch( event.keyCode ) {
            ...
            case keyCode.UP:
                self._move( "previous", event );
                // prevent moving cursor to beginning of text field in some browsers
                event.preventDefault();
                break;
            case keyCode.DOWN:
                self._move( "next", event );
                // prevent moving cursor to end of text field in some browsers
                event.preventDefault();
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to workaround this issue in an unminified version of Autocomplete using an isOpen boolean to track the state of the Autocomplete component.

This at the very top of the file:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

var requestIndex = 0;
var isOpen = false; // NEW
```

Then at the top of the _suggest function:

```
isOpen = true; // NEW
```

Then at the top of the close function:

```
isOpen = false; // NEW
```

Then in the key binding function:

```
case keyCode.UP:
self._move( "previous", event );
if ( isOpen )                 // NEW
     event.preventDefault();  // NEW
break;
case keyCode.DOWN:
self._move( "next", event );
if ( isOpen )                 // NEW
     event.preventDefault();  // NEW
break;
```

This should probably be folded into the real release, but I'm nto sure how to go about making that happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will be fixed in the upcoming 1.9 release:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7639

You can either edit the current release version or try the incomplete 1.9:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui

One nice thing about 1.9 is autocomplete now supports contenteditable divs.